# Passing values to next page C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In my code, after i choose the value in the drop down list and hit enter it send the first value of the drop down list instead

May I know what are the possible causes?

Below is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DayBox.Text != "" && MonthBox.Text != "" && YearBox.Text != "")
    {
        string date;
        int container = Convert.ToInt32(DayBox.Text);

        if (container < 10)
        {
            date = String.Format("0{0}/{1}/{2}", DayBox.Text, MonthBox.Text, YearBox.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            date = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", DayBox.Text, MonthBox.Text, YearBox.Text);
        }


        Session["DATE"] = date;
        Session["IPADDRESS"] = IPDropDownList.Text;

        Response.Redirect("IPAddressDay.aspx");
    }
}
```

Code for the dropdown box:

```
//this if statment is for gettting the ip address for that Month;
if (DayBox.Text == "" && MonthBox.Text != "" && YearBox.Text != "")
{
    IPDropDownList.Items.Clear();

    string date;
    date = String.Format("{0}/{1}",MonthBox.Text, YearBox.Text);

    sqlStatment = String.Format("SELECT IPAddress FROM IPActivity WHERE AccessDate LIKE '%{0}' GROUP BY IPAddress;", date);

    MyDataSet = RetriveDataBase(connection, sqlStatment, tableName);//method written by me

    dra = MyDataSet.Tables[tableName].Rows;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
    {
        IPDropDownList.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
    }
     //this is to close the if statment for gettting the ip address for that Month;
}
```

Description:
It will not read the value I choose, but take the first value instead and send to next page

Comment: sends the value where? Elaborate please

Comment: where do you fill the dropdownlist ? in Page_Load event ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you fill your DropDownList at your `Page_Load` event, you need to use `IsPostBack`. Everytime you hit the button `Page_Load` event is fired before your `Button1_Click` event. Therefore, at your `Button1_Click` you get the first value in dropdownlist always. Correct code should be,

```
if (!IsPostBack && DayBox.Text == "" && MonthBox.Text != "" && YearBox.Text != "")
{
    IPDropDownList.Items.Clear();

    string date = String.Format("{0}/{1}",MonthBox.Text, YearBox.Text);

    sqlStatment = String.Format("SELECT IPAddress FROM IPActivity WHERE AccessDate LIKE '%{0}' GROUP BY IPAddress;", date);

    MyDataSet = RetriveDataBase(connection, sqlStatment, tableName);

    foreach (DataRow dr in MyDataSet.Tables[tableName].Rows;)
    {
        IPDropDownList.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
    }   
}
```

Comment: nevayeshirazi
THX for the help but i want the value to change whenever the date the user change the date. if i add IsPostBack the vaule wont be able to change. Can u advise me?

Comment: How do you change the date ? I mean as far as I understand from you code, it is just a string in textboxes ?

Comment: I change the date by allowing user to choose their date from another DDL then inserting into the sql can get from database

Comment: You can assign OnSelectedIndexChanged event to DDL that users select date from.Use this event to update your date info instead of Page_Load. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do u have a example how i use that cause i am very new to Asp .net

Comment: `<asp:DropDownList ID="DateDropDown" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventNameToChangeDate" AutoPostBack="true" >`

Such definition of DDL should work for you. EventNameToChangeDate is the event that you should define at your Page_Load.

Comment: Do i create    protected void EventNameToChangeDate(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Yes `protected void EventNameToChangeDate(object sender, EventArgs e)` is correct.

Comment: You are welcome. I would be glad if you can mark my answer as correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Session["IPADDRESS"] = IPDropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

then, to set the value:

```
IPDropDownList.SelectedValue = Session["IPADDRESS"] != null ? Session["IPADDRESS"].ToString() : "" ;
```

And don't reset your dropdownlist if you're posting back.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   //Code to set dropdownlist values here
}
```

Comment: Hi ChuckTHX for the help but i want the value to change whenever the date the user change the date. if i add IsPostBack the vaule wont be able to change. Can u advise me? – RUiHAO

Comment: By NOT using IsPostBack every time the page loads you rebind the dropdown list and wipe out the user's selected value.  You only want to bind the list when the page initially loads.

Comment: Chuck showed you what you need -- put your code to bind the dropdown in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
Session["IPADDRESS"] = IPDropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

As select boxes have a value property which gets the value of the option which can differ from the text displayed.

Comment: Hi Jamie, I tried but it still doesn't work. 

When the button is hit 
the page is reload which cause it to take the first value of the DDL

Comment: Could you show the code for the dropdown control and how you are populating it?

Comment: I've attached it to my question